# ASP 4.0 References in 2.0 project

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, .net-3.5

I loaded an .NET 3.5 Solution, Web applicaton locally on VS2010,
This was a working version running ASP 2.0, VS2010 does this conversion thing, I get ik built again, the website runs locally  on my laptop, works fine. I did some developing.

Now I want to install it in our Test-server, I notice my app pools on the laptop are 4.0, but I am asked tot keep the WebApp 4.0, All projects still use .NET 3.5, Configuring my setup projects to install to ASP 2.0 works, installation works. The webapp wont load on server because, lots of references in my web and websvcs are runtime v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change you references to an earlier version or change the version of the .NET runtime of your app pool?

Comment: true, off course I wasn't going to change each reference by hand, It just took me a while to figure out how to change the runtime of my web projects